# Android Realm: compactRealmFile NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using  `Realm version 0.80.1` and my code is below :

```
  Realm realm_ = null;
  try {
       realm_ = Realm.getInstance(new File(func.getFolder("db")), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
       realm_.beginTransaction();
       RealmResults<AllAuthors> allauthors = realm_.where(AllAuthors.class).findAll();
       allauthors.clear();
       realm_.commitTransaction();
      } finally {
       if(realm_ != null) {
           realm_.compactRealmFile(getActivity(), func.getFolder("db") + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
           realm_.close();
       }
  }
```

But the program gives an error `NullPointerException` in a row

```
realm_.compactRealmFile(getActivity(), func.getFolder("db") + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
```

`func.getFolder("db")` gives me the full path of the directory on the SD card.

What am I doing wrong?

Stack:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.gorayalexander.samlibreaderlike/com.gorayalexander.samlibreaderlike.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at io.realm.Realm.compactRealmFile(Realm.java:1731)
            at io.realm.Realm.compactRealmFile(Realm.java:1781)
            at com.gorayalexander.samlibreaderlike.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:145)
            at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5436)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Piyush Gupta - Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You cannot compact an open Realm. You should do `realm_.close();` first.

Comment: geisshirt - Still the same error.

Comment: Split the row up that you get NullPointerException on so you know exactly what variables that is null. Is it realm_? Is it func? Is it some other var?

Comment: Checked all the variables. They give the same result. I think that it is not a variable.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, it is hard to tell what could be wrong without it?

Comment: ChristianMelchior - Updated

Comment: Please update code and stacktrace where you separate all the parameters  on a separate line before the call to compactRealmFile() and test that no input to compactRealmFile is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling that function in `onDestroy()` are you sure that your `getActivity()` doesn't return null?

Comment: Я пробовал и такой код, но все равно не работает:

Comment: Я пробовал и такой код, но все равно не работает:     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        realm = Realm.getInstance(new File(func.getFolder("db")), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
        String pth = realm.getPath();
        if (realm!=null) realm.close();
        //realm.beginTransaction();
        //func.showLog(func.getFolder("db") + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
        realm.compactRealmFile(this, pth);
        //realm.commitTransaction();
    }

Comment: Sorry, I posted several times not formatted comment